# Non-isomorphic graphs with same spectrum counting multiplicities

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

This question has been asked [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520807/not-isomorphic-graphs-with-same-spectrum-exists) several times but all the answers I came across gave the example where the spectrum was considered without counting multiplicities of the eigenvalues.

So can we find non-isomorphic graphs with same spectrum (where spectrum includes the multiplicities of eigenvalues also)?

Obviously, if I am given the spectrum along with the eigenvectors then I can get back the matrix (adjacency/laplacian) and hence the graph. But if I skip the information about eigenvectors how much do I lose?

I am also asking this because in my little study so far, I have only seen how eigenvalues reveal information about graphs (like connectivity, bipartite, approximate max-cut, independent set/colouring, etc). I have not seen how eigenvectors can be helpful for understanding graphs except for the little fact that they can be used to give a "nice" embedding of the graph on a plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give a reference for your claim in the first paragraph? When people talk about isospectral graphs this almost always means isospectral including multiplicities. The examples on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory) article on isospectral graphs include multiplicities. Methods to generate isospectral graphs like Seidel switching include multiplicities. If anything you might get a new research question if you consider isospectrality without matching multiplicities.

Comment: I have added the link to the similar question which was asked before on MSE.

Comment: But thanks. I remember reading that G is connected $\implies$ largest eigenvalue has multiplicity 1. So, I just assumed that the vice-versa should also be true. But the example you stated of $C_4∪K_1$ is a counterexample. So I am wondering how to deduce connectivity from adjacency eigenvalues? (although, laplacian multiplicity of smallest eigenvalue can determine connectivity)

Comment: @kishlaya: The adjacency matrix of $C_4\cup K_1$ is cospectral with that of $K_{1,4}$, so you cannot determine connectivity from the spectrum of the adjacency matrix.